# median filter for color images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

When performing median filtering on grayscale images we rank the intensity values of pixels. How do we rank intensity values of pixels in color images as each pixel has 3 channels R,G,B. What is the formula.Thank You.

Comment: YOu can use split() function to have three images of original RGB one, apply median filter for each one separately then use merge() function to get the filtered original image

Comment: If i use im.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0] to access B value               im.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1] to access G value                     im.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2] to access R value.                                     Then among the ranked values of B, the median value of B is selected. Among values of G, the median value of G is selected and among values of R, the median value of R is selected for the centre pixel. It gives us a median filtered image. Is it correct??

Comment: The solution depends on what do you need the results for, what is your goal?

Comment: would you please put your code we talking about ?

Comment: I mean color image has three channels, B,G and R. We can access B using im.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0]. It gives the value of B component for a particular pixel in image. Similarly we can get other values of B in the neighborhood. For example if we consider 3*3 neighborhood we will get 9 values of B. We will rank these values and calculate the median value among these values and store it in the cetre pixel valur for B component. Similarly we can get 9 values for G component and can calculate the median value and store in the centre pixl for G component . This is done again for R component. Wil it work?

Comment: @shoham I want to remove impulse noise using median filtering and I am creating my own and not using opencv built in median filter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here are 2 options for noise filtering with median filter:

1. do the median filter for each on of the RGB components separately, this is not a good choice, because the components are correlated, and false colors may appear.
2. you can also convert to HSV from RGB and then do the median filter on the hue, saturation and value, then convert back to RGB, this method is usually better (for most applications).

HSV description:

[image]

Comment: Please tell me some link from where i can study about the points you mentioned .Thanks.

Comment: here are some links:

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-13208-7_4#page-1

http://books.google.co.il/books?id=SlXgTyQ86VsC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=median+filter+hsv&source=bl&ots=5vyM0cWtFd&sig=M1Um0kQHaw258vnJDZDT43UiaG0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LjUJVNbXEIboPNKMgNAC&ved=0CBoQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=median%20filter%20hsv&f=false

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: Converting to HSV doesn't alter the main problem -- you are still trying to sort a list of ordered triples. If you are using one of the three for your sort key then it makes sense (e.g., sort on brightness V).

Answer (score 10):

One of the options is vector median filter (VMF). See [Fast Modified Vector Median Filter](http://www.comm.toronto.edu/~kostas/Publications2008/pub/proceed/38.pdf) for detailed algorithm description and efficient implementation. One of the features of VMF is that it doesn't produce "false" colors - only the actual colors present in original image are used in filtered image.

Comment: Thanks Paul for this interesting article. Its main point is to remove the noisy pixel at the center of the window from the computation, which really makes sense. The authors decrease the scoring function R0 of the center of the window by a constant beta.
To avoid to determine beta, I propose to weight R by the number of pixels it is based on. One can use the average in R formula or apply a scaling to Rk. In Fig1, Rk would be multiplied by 4/3 and compared to R0. In Fig1, there is an error in R2 formula IMHO.